# Why have two different string-variables with the same content the same reference?

Tags: c#

```
var str1 = "C#";
var str2 = "F#";    
var str3 = "C#";

Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(str1, str2)); // False
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(str1, str3)); // True <-- Why?
```

I know that strings are immutable reference types, which means that the objects can not be changed. But that doesn´t explain why the two strings refer to the same object.

Comment: C#'s compiler puts extra effort to intern strings it sees in user code. When they're loaded at runtime, they reference same string in dll

Comment: From spec: The Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) guarantees that the result of two `ldstr` instructions referring to two metadata tokens that have the same sequence of characters return precisely the same string object (a process known as "string interning").

Comment: `"C#` and `"F#` in your code are compile-time constants whose references are assigned to the `str1`, `str2`, `str3` variables. Since strings are immutable, the compiler can create just one shared instance of each string (stored in the assembly itself) and pass references to it to all variables that need it.

Answer (score 5):

For *literals* (i.e. strings that appear in your code) and other constant string values (i.e. the result of a string operation that can be calculated entirely at compile-time), the compiler uses the [`ldstr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr) operation which loads an *interned* (i.e. shared) instance of the string - on the basis that literals in your code typically get reused a *lot* and it would be suboptimal to constantly allocate new string instances. Hence they have the same reference. To quote from the `ldstr` documentation:

> The Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) guarantees that the result of two ldstr instructions referring to two metadata tokens that have the same sequence of characters return precisely the same string object (a process known as "string interning").

Since string instances are immutable, this is fine (at least notionally; in reality people can *always* mutate immutable data via unsafe code etc, but that comes under the heading of "play stupid games, win stupid prizes").

If you had loaded those values from `char[]`, or decoded from `byte[]`, or as the result of string operations etc: they would be different strings that just *happened* to have the same contents.

Answer (score 3):

This is called string interning. C# compiler will intern [string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#quoted-string-literals), i.e. leveraging string immutability it adds them to special storage in assembly where the same literals reference the same instance, so space is  conserved. Consider the following example:

```
var str1 = "C#";
var str2 = "F#";    
var str3 = "C#";
var str4 = String.Concat("C", "#");

Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(str1, str2)); // False
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(str1, str3)); // True 
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(str1, str4)); // False
```

Since the `str4` is constructed "dynamically" it will not be interned which will result in new string instance created, hence `False` (though `str1.Equals(str4)` is `True`)

See also:

- [String.Intern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?view=net-7.0#remarks)
- [Does the CLR intern string constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54659778/2501279)
- [Comparing two objects with == operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71981008/2501279) - runtime (some versions) can cache some of `int.ToString()` resulting in something like `Object.ReferenceEquals("1".ToString(), "1")` being `True`.
- [String interning in .NET Framework - What are the benefits and when to use interning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054522/2501279)